# TortoiseGit automatic login

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Yesterday, I got my TortoiseGit set up and It's doing really great at the moment.

Only 1 thing bothers me, whenever I commit and I want to push, I have to type in my username and password. Is there any way to make TortoiseGit login automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use [pageant](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and load your SSH-Key. Pageant is included in the putty installer or as an single programm.

Comment: Thanks so far! I generated a SSH-Key with putty and saved it on my computer and in my Github repository. I also loaded the SSH-Key with pageant. Now, how do I get the authentication working?

Comment: you need to specify thay you're using the SSH protocol to whatever remote your are push to. git remote set-url remotename user@domain:repo.git usually this syntax means ssh is implicit